# looking for a way to display UIView in SKSpriteNode

Tags: view, uiview, sprite, skspritenode

I am looking for a way to display view within an skspritenode, kind of like you can display an image in an skspritenode. My end goal here would be to use core animator to animate some images and then have those animated images as the skspritenode and not just the static images as i have now.